# Trying to fill file with fwrite() from allocated memory

Tags: c

On my project I have this structure that has some things in it. I am asked to allocate memory, give it values and store those values in memory. Then (and I know this is weird) I am asked to move the values in memory to a file.

This is the gist of what's going on:

File1.h

```
typedef struct s1{
   int a;
   double b;
   char c;
} THING;
```

File2.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "File1.h"     // Note File1.h must be in the same directory as File2.c

int main(void)
{
   THING *ptr = malloc(sizeof(THING));
   if(ptr == NULL)
   {
       fprintf(stderr,"Memory could not be allocated!");
       return 1;
   }

   ptr->a = 10;
   ptr->b = 25.4;
   ptr->c = 'A';

   /*code goes here to move from memory to file*/

   return 0;   
}
```

I'm thinking I use something like this:

```
fwrite(&ptr, sizeof(ptr), 1, filename);
```

but for some reason that doesn't work. Nothing gets written.

Also, to check if it worked I would make the line like this (I'm guessing):

```
if( (fwrite(&ptr, sizeof(ptr), 1, filename)) != 1 )
{
    printf("Thing not copied to file!");
}
```

Comment: You are off my one level of indirection with each `ptr` argument to `fwrite`. `ptr` is already a pointer, you do not need to take its address again with `'&'`. `sizeof (ptr)` is nothing but `sizeof (a_pointer)` and you want `sizeof (*ptr)` which is `sizeof (THING)`. And then since struct padding can differ from compiler to compiler, there is no guarantee writing with `fwrite (ptr, sizeof *ptr, 1, filename)` to file would be portable (but shoudn't present a problem for testing purposes on the same machine) You also need to check the return of `fwrite` to ensure it succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Files are streams of bytes. To write data to a file, you must create a stream of bytes that holds the data in the file in some comprehensible format. Your `THING` structure isn't guaranteed to have any particular representation and so there is no guarantee that you will be able to read it back from the file and make sense of it.

Your code will work if you change `sizeof(ptr)` to `sizeof(*ptr)`. But it will only be working by luck. You should learn how to serialize data from native data into a stream of bytes in some defined format.

Comment: Also need to change `&ptr` to `ptr`.

Comment: @Inian That is not a comment on my answer. Could you please delete it?